# SVN Notifications via GMAIL SMTP

Tags: python, linux, svn, ubuntu, smtp

I have got SVN running on Ubuntu 11.04 32bit and now want notifications using my GMAIL account for every commit.

I've commited a few things but don't actually recieve the commit emails for them. There aren't any errors that are displayed and I have looked through the logs but haven't found much useful information as of yet.

I've read quite alot of posts regarding this and editing the following files below including what they contain now. I've tried using sendmail and postfix but have had no luck with them hence which is why I am using Google's mail server.  It would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction or an alternative approach.

The links I found and have used.

http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2009/12/use-gmail-smtp-server-for-post-commit.html

http://iffee.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/svn-commit-to-google-apps-email-notification/

**post-commit.tmpl**

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

/home/megaz/svn/repos/ya/hooks/mailer.py commit "$REPOS" \
"$REV" /home/megaz/svn/repos/ya/hooks/mailer.conf
```

**mailer.conf**

```
[general]
smtp_hostname = smtp.gmail.com:587
smtp_username = #mygmailaddress
smtp_password = #mygmailpassword
smtp_use_ssl = true
smtp_use_tls = 1

[defaults]
diff = /usr/bin/diff -u -L %(label_from)s -L %(label_to)s %(from)s %(to)s
commit_subject_prefix = [SVN-Commit]
propchange_subject_prefix =
lock_subject_prefix =
unlock_subject_prefix =
from_addr = #my from address 
to_addr = #my to address 
reply_to = #my replyto address 
generate_diffs = none
show_nonmatching_paths = yes

[maps]
```

**mailer.py**

```
class SMTPOutput(MailedOutput):
   def start(self, group, params):
     MailedOutput.start(self, group, params)
     self.buffer = StringIO()
     self.write = self.buffer.write
     self.write(self.mail_headers(group, params))
   def finish(self):
     server = smtplib.SMTP(self.cfg.general.smtp_hostname)
     # 2009-12-13 asadomov: add ssl configuration (e.g. for gmail smtp server)
     if self.cfg.is_set('general.smtp_use_ssl') and self.cfg.general.smtp_use_ssl.lower() == "true":
       server.ehlo()
       server.starttls()
       server.ehlo()
     if self.cfg.is_set('general.smtp_username'):
       server.login(self.cfg.general.smtp_username,
                    self.cfg.general.smtp_password)
     server.sendmail(self.from_addr, self.to_addrs, self.buffer.getvalue())
     server.quit()
```

Comment: Please edit your post to add what exactly the problem is, the error output, etc. Also, it's good to phrase your "question" as a question.

Comment: My apologies, I don't receive the commit emails within the email addresses that are specified in mailer.conf.

Comment: `mailer.py` doesn't seem to actually do anything, it's just a class definition, or did you post only part of the file? Anyway, try to get it to work ftom the command line to start with.

Answer (score 1):

I see, you have not really read the instructions. The code you have copy/pasted needs to replace a snippet in a larger file which you haven't downloaded. Also, the file name of the post-commit script should not have the `.templ` suffix; that's what they use for inactive example / template files in the distribution.

Perhaps this explains why you couldn't get Sendmail to work, either. At this point I'd recommend to go back to that, as it's simpler.

Comment: Where do you download mailer.py from?  I guess it would explain why I had troubles and to be honest this is the first time I have actually done this sort of stuff.

Comment: Read the blog articles you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

1. rename your "post-commit.templ" to "post-commit"
2. make sure you give exec rights (such as 755) to "post-commit"